# Where do I implement the settings html of my TYPO3 extension?

Tags: typo3, content-management-system, typo3-9.x, typo3-extensions

I am currently developing my own TYPO3 extension (in v 9.5.11) and I want to know where I have to reference the Html file that is supposed to open when you click on Admin Tools-->MyExtension in the TYPO3 sidebar.

[image: Typo3 Sidebar]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This completely depends on how you integrated your extension; there are at least two (vanilla, Extbase) ways to make such modules. Where your template file (which is Fluid, not pure HTML) exists depends on the integration and your TypoScript configuration that defines template paths, but by default it would be in your extension, in the sub path `Resources/Private/Templates/$controllerName` where `$controlerName` is the name of the controller that renders your plugin.

Note that template paths for frontend and backend are configured separately.

If you use the vanilla way of making backend modules you most likely need to define this template manually, by setting it in the view, in which case it can be placed anywhere you like (but should of course be inside your extension).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at system extension `extensionmanager`, where the backend module has some registered controller classes, and methods in ext_tables.php. fx class `ListController`, with `indexAction`, `unresolvedDependenciesAction`, `terAction`, ... and more methods:

```
'List' => 'index,unresolvedDependencies,ter,showAllVersions,distributions',
```

`ListController` class like all other controller classes uses FLUID views, which is looking for HTML templates inside `Resources/Private/Templates/<CONTROLLERNAME>/...`

For `ListController->indexAction` it would be `Resources/Private/Templates/List/Index.html` where you can use TYPO3 FLUID functionality.

See also https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/BackendModules/TemplateClass/Index.html

Answer (score 0):

Well, It is always recommended to write your question clearly and bit more detail so people can understand quickly.

Anyway as I understand the question, you're talking about view resource file. If you have created your extension with Extension builder, your action file will automatically be generated in the Resource folder.

BE module directory will be `Resources/Private/Backend` See the example [here](https://github.com/GhanshyamBhava/webuser/tree/master/Resources/Private/Backend).

In the TypoScript, you will get the source path this will something look like [this](https://github.com/GhanshyamBhava/webuser/blob/master/Configuration/TypoScript/setup.ts#L57-L68).

To check the backend default action, you can see the backend module configuration [here](https://github.com/GhanshyamBhava/webuser/blob/master/ext_tables.php#L16-L29). From here you will get better idea which action will be call by default (Probably List action)

In this directory, you will have all the HTML you need. Hope this will help you!